# Relationship of x regress y and y regress x on the slope

Tags: regression, variance, covariance, linear

Consider a linear regression model y on x and x on y. We have

$Y = a'X + a$ where $a' = \frac{cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)}$. Equivalently, we have $X = b'Y+b$ where $b' = \frac{cov(X,Y)}{Var(Y)}$. I am interested in the relationship between $a'$ and $b'$

Clearly, if $Var(X) = Var(Y)$ then we have $a'=b'$. However, say we want $a' = \frac{1}{b'}$. It follows that:

\begin{aligned}
a' &= \frac{1}{b'} \\
\frac{cov(X,Y)}{Var(X)} &= \frac{Var(Y)}{cov(X,Y)} \\
\frac{1}{Var(X)} &= Var(Y)
\end{aligned}

Ok. What about this example then, where

\begin{aligned}
y &= 2x \\
\frac{1}{2}y &= x \\
&\text{but} \\
Var(Y) &= 4Var(X) \\
\end{aligned}

Clearly we have $a' = \frac{1}{b'}$ but our variances are not inverses of one another. Where is my understanding faulty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

you are wrong in third line.  cov(x,y) won't get cancel out. It will be squared.

Comment: I am a fool! Thank you. Does it hold then that $a' = \frac{1}{b'}$ whenever $cov(x,y) != 0$?

Comment: yes it is. cov(x,y) == 0 means that they don't have any relationship thus can't draw any regression line between them.